# What is the fastest approach using JavaScript to search a big set of key value pairs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, switch-statement

I have a ReactJS application that gets data from a remote API and shows it. The data returned contains an Activity ID, which corresponds to an Activity name. The database for Activities is not easily accessible for me though. The same case happens with Account and Location for example.

My approach was to create a JS file for each of Account, Activity, Location, add one method in each that takes the ID, a big switch inside that matches ID with the list of IDs inside it and returns required name.

This approach worked fine for Account and Location, which had 800 and 170 cases respectively. When it came to the Activity that has 11000 cases, `npm run build` is now taking ages to run (I terminated after more than 15 mins passed).

My question is: does the time taken by npm run build correspond to the file size or the syntax of the code inside? Will this approach cause problems if I let `npm run build` take its time? Or is there a better and faster way to do this, like map for example?

Edit: This is an example for the data:

```
Account ID: 113300512
Account Name: 113300512:account1
```

Sample:

```
switch(id) {
    case "170501010001":
    return "170501010001: Text in arabic"
    case "170501010002":
    return "170501010002: Text in arabic"
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide the detailed structure of Account, Location & Cases.

Comment: I added an example for the data, they all follow the same structure, a numerical value for ID and a String for Name

Comment: What about the Cases?  Can you please provide a sample case ?

Comment: switch(id) {
    case "170501010001":
    return "170501010001: Sample text in arabic"
    case "170501010002":
    return "170501010002: Sample text in arabic"

Answer (score 0):

This could be one of the solution.

Create a class with methods, Stote - to store, find - to find.
I will not recommend to use switch case.

**AccountRepository.js**

```
'use strict';

class AccountRepository {
    constructor() {
        this.accountReadings = new Map();
    }

    store(id, value) {
        this.accountReadings.set(id, value);
    }

    find(id) {
        if (this.accountReadings.has(id)) {
            return this.accountReadings.get(id);
        } else {
            return [];
        }
    }
}

module.exports = new AccountRepository();
```

**And to use.**

```
import AccountRepository from './AccountRepository';

AccountRepository.store(...);

AccountRepository.find(...);
```

Comment: But this way I will have to do AccountRepository.store(...); 11000 times?

Comment: you can avoid the store if you have the structure correct such as "new Map([[ 1, 'one' ],[ 2, 'two' ]]))". Else you can use the store method - it should work fine with out performance issue.